# Should I work and create files in mysite or mysite/mysite?

Tags: django

[image]

I just started using **django 1.4** and I realized that inside `mysite` there is another folder called `mysite` which has the same files as `mysite`.

Should I work and create files in `mysite` or `mysite/mysite?`

Comment: Had the same question sometime ago, looking forward to see the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with django 1.4, the default project structure changed, moving your main project files down into a packages. Apps will live in packages parallel to the main project.

[Updated default project layout and manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py)

Though your layout example does not look like the default 1.4. Models should live in apps that you create. Run the following command in your project:

```
python manage.py startapp myapp
```

To get a layout like this:

```
manage.py
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
mysite/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

Comment: I'm following the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: Sorry I made a quick correction. You should be creating an app for your models and views.

Comment: So `myapp` is like `polls` in my example? So it means I'm doing it right? But, the confusing thing is that in order to configure my database I had to edit `mysite/mysite/settings.py` not `mysite/settings.py` is that a normal procedure?

Comment: There should not be a settings in that top root level. Are you sure this was all created from a single django 1.4 startproject command? The only thing for me the root is manage.py